# Selecting specific dynamic elements. jQuery / HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a list of DIVs, with each DIV populated from my db. I use some apex to grab my data,

'optionPanel' is hidden with display:none. When showPanel() is clicked, 'optionPanel' appears. What I want, is for 'optionPanel' to only appear on the specific DIV I click, right now it appears on all of them.

```
<a data-ajax="false" onclick="showPanel();" class="job">
<div class="details">
    <span class="name">Name</span><span class="value">{! contact.salutation + ' ' + contact.firstname + ' ' + contact.lastname }</span><br></br>
    <span class="name">Title</span><span class="value">{! contact.title}</span><br></br>
    <span class="dep">Department</span><span class="value">{! contact.department}</span><br></br>
    <div class="optionPanel">{! contact.phone}</div>
</div>
</a>
```

My function is pretty basic right now,

```
function showPanel(){
    $('.optionPanel').toggle();
};
```

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Obviously, right now, anything with the class name optionPanel is gonna appear, how do I get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: pass 'this' as argument of showPanel() function then use it to target the specific element. There are thousand of samples like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `this` reference to your onclick handler
try this

**html**

```
 <a data-ajax="false" onclick="showPanel(this);" class="job">
                        //---------------^^^^---here
```

**jquery**

```
 function showPanel(obj){
        $(obj).find('div.optionPanel').toggle();
    };
```

**OR avoiding inline function**

```
 $('a.job').click(function(){
   $(this).find('div.optionPanel').toggle();
 });
```

Comment: Perfect! Cheers bipen!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the inline 'onclick` handler and attach it via jQuery

```
$(".job").on("click",function(){
    $(this).find(".optionPanel").toggle()
})
```

This will only toggle the `optionPanel` for the respective `a` that was clicked